# Zombie heroku process after deleting project?

Tags: heroku, discord.js

Has anyone experienced deleted heroku projects that still runs on some undiscoverable process?

I've been hosting a discord bot on heroku on a single free worker dyno, here's a timeline of what happend:

1. On 4/25 migrated to a github deployment repo.
2. At some point starting 4/29 between 10:45 to 11:30pm, I started
   receiving duplicate bot messages.
3. On 4/30 I attempted to deploy an update thinking there was a bug in my code, but after observed the following symptoms when I dug deeper:
   a. messages I attempted to stop sending are still being sent, but only once
   b. messages both the old and new version of the code sends are still being duplicated
   c. Heroku logs continue to show code execution even when I disable the only worker dyno
4. From here I suspected the project have a zombie process, so I attempted to deleted the project and added a new copy of the project, but the same behavior continues.

I have no reason to suspect it was caused by code running else where: I only ever deployed the code on heroku. The discord tokens are being kept in heroku configs and copies of the code could not really be sending messages without.

What could be happening and what should I do next?

Comment: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2236

Comment: Ah I checked for incidents over the weekend while debugging and didn't see any. That also explains why everything went back to normal at noon. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your token and re-inputting it into heroku.

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question.